# How to create a large zoomed image in python

Tags: python, image, graph, numpy, save

Hi I currently have a graph of many data points with error bars and I was wondering how I can create an image from this that is very long horizontally.

This image is made up of 11, 256-point graphs appended on each-other. I would like to create an image (.png) that has 256 points in it when it opens but can be scrolled to the right to see more of the same image.

Thanks!

Comment: How does it open at the moment?

Comment: It opens zoomed out so you see all 2600 points at once. I can zoom in in the window and see what I want but I don't know how to save it so it is both zoomed in and wide enough that I can see all of the points on a smaller scale.

Comment: I believe this is a property of the OS, not of the image itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice script that you can use that use from [Jonas Wagner](http://29a.ch/2009/5/14/concatenating-images-using-python). Plus, it uses the cool python builtin function map() that I have never used before this.

```
from PIL import Image
import sys

if not len(sys.argv) > 3:
    raise SystemExit("Usage: %s src1 [src2] .. dest" % sys.argv[0])

images = map(Image.open, sys.argv[1:-1])
w = sum(i.size[0] for i in images)
mh = max(i.size[1] for i in images)

result = Image.new("RGBA", (w, mh))

x = 0
for i in images:
    result.paste(i, (x, 0))
    x += i.size[0]

result.save(sys.argv[-1])
```

Comment: Just a reminder - opening all images at once might cause your Python interpreter to eat a big chunk of memory without releasing it unless quit.